# My vba code closes a document before the print command can be executed

Tags: excel, vba, printing, ms-word

The code I am trying to run is in excel vba and its supposed to open a word document print it and then close the document. For some reason it seems that the code doesn't finish sending the document to the printer and yet it still closes. So the code runs to completion and doesn't generate an error message but nothing manages to print.

When I run the code step by step the document does manage to print. I tried adding: Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) to give it time to work. I tried a another form of that line in case the program was telling word to wait instead of excel: Excel.Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")). I've also tried playing around with the time making it wait 10 second instead of 5.

Any help would be great

```
If ENG28 = "" Then
Else
  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ENG28)
  objWord.Visible = True

  objDoc.PrintOut 
  Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
  objWord.Quit 0
End If
```

Comment: Print jobs often take up to a minute to complete. As an alternative to Wait, look into Sleep and DoEvents loops, one of those may work better for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you made use of the .Wait method however there is a better way as you can never guarantee that your document is in a printed state within the 5-10 seconds threshold.

The PrintOut method basically has an argument you may add named Background. The default value of this argument is True which would mean that printing occurs in the background and the code continues to run which is causing your file to close before completing the print function. In this case, if you set the Background argument value to False, the macro will not take any more instructions until the printing is done.

try changing the PrinOut line to the following, see if that helps:

```
objDoc.PrintOut Background:=False
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!